# Ember Integration Testing, How to use wait to build a custom Helper?

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, helper

I don't understand how to use the wait helper provided by the Ember.Test package to build our own helpers. The few that I understood, is that we must return systematically "wait(...)" at the end of our helpers.
But how report that my asynchronous operation is done ? We can pass a parameter to the wait method, so I thought that I could pass it a promise, and resolve the promise when my asynchronous operation is done ... But it doesn't work :D

To illustrate my idea I did a JSBIN with an example : http://jsbin.com/OxeniTO/30/

```
App = Em.Application.create({
  rootElement:"#ember-app"
});

App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();
App.advanceReadiness();


test('Wait 1000ms and fail',function(){
  visit('/').then(function(){
    var promise = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function(){
      ok(false, "Assertion failed");
      promise.resolve();
    }, 1000);

    ok(true, "Assert passed");

    return wait(promise);
  });
});
```

In this case, the Ember.Test.Adapter for Qunit doesn't wait the promise resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Try to wrap your resolving promise in `Ember.run.later` instead of using `setTimeout`:

```
...
Ember.run.later(function(){
  ok(false, "Assertion failed");
  promise.resolve();
}, 1000);
...
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezoGAT/2/edit)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer, but this code use a detail of the implementation. I look closer the code of the 'wait' method and it appears that the conditions to continue to waiting, are :
- That the router is loading
- That an ajax request is in progress
- That a call is scheduled by the the RunLoop (with the Em.Run.next, later, etc)
- That a Run loop is in progress

So the good solution for me if I want wait anything in an Helper could be call a Em.run.begin() to start waiting and call Em.run.end () at the end ...

I upgrade the demo here :http://jsbin.com/ikaROjU/1/